# Why freshdesk sso always return "login was unsuccessful" (302)?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, integration, freshdesk

Im trying to use Freshdesk Simple SSO.

My generated string is:

> https://companyname.freshdesk.com/login/sso?name=test&email=test@companyname.com&hash=220685100fbad0bdd17e9096313395b7&timestamp=1472786454

but Freshdesk always return error "login was unsuccessful" on the page with code 302.

Any advice?

PS: there is mistake in their java code example: they missed 'timestamp' param in the generated url but it is required param.

> timestamp The UTC timestamp of when the user attempts to log in
>   remotely in seconds since epoch. This value has to be within the past
>   30 minutes. Else the hash is rejected and the user is denied login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a link to github with two examples on [their article](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/31166).

The [first one](https://github.com/kirandarisi/freshdesk_sso_java/blob/master/FreshDeskSSOServlet.java) is with MD5.
The [second one](https://github.com/kirandarisi/freshdesk_sso_java/blob/master/FDHmac.java) is with HmacMD5.

I used first one because I'm doing web app but looks like actual example is the second one because they are using HmacMD5 algorithm on their side.

Comment: Please include the solution in your answer, not only as links - as links go stale